# How to declare an object with key being a date and value being a boolean in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, object

Having the file `app.component.ts`, inside its class it is declared a variable of which stores from the input a date.

I want with that date to create an object, the key being the date and the value being a boolean ( which is true or false depending on the date, for example if the date is inside year 2018 it is false, otherwise it's true)

Html file:

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="currentDate">
<button (click)="addDate()">add date</button>
```

ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    dateArray = [];
    currentDate = "";
    dateObject = { this.currentDate, true };
    addDate() {
         this.dateArray.push(dateObject);
    }
}
```

I'm new to Angular, I don't know how `dateObject` should look like in order to store in it what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: The answer is to use `{[this.currentDate]: true}` but you should initialise `dateObject` inside `addDate` otherwise you will only append the same object each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
export class AppComponent {
    dateArray = [];
    currentDate = "";
    addDate() {
      const currentYear = new Date(this.currentDate).getFullYear();
      if (currentYear === 2018) { 
        this.dateArray.push({
          [this.currentDate]: true
        });
      }

    }
}
```

You can convert the `currentDate` string into a JavaScript Date Object, followed by using the [Date.getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) method to get the year.

Then, you can proceed to check if the year is 2018, before pushing the object into the `dateArray`.

In addition, the way you are initialising the `dateObject` is a wrong use of working with [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). For this scenario, you should be working with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) instead, such as `{ [this.currentDate]: true }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that contains the properties that you want.
Example

```
export class MyCustomClass {
   public currentDate: Date;
   public isDateValid: boolean;
   constructor(currentDate: Date) {
     this.currentDate = currentDate;
     if(currentDate.getFullYear() < 2018) { 
        this.isDateValid = false;
     } else {
        this.isDateValid = true;
     }
   }
}
```

Then you can create a instance of MyCustomClass in the AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent {
    dateArray: MyCustomClass[] = [];
    currentDate = "";
    newObj: MyCustomClass;
    addDate() {
         newObj = new MyCustomClass(currentDate);
         this.dateArray.push(newObj);
    }
}
```

Is that what you need?